# Weird characters using Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, unicode

in my program, I am encrypting and decrypting a .PNG file using the Triple DES algorithm.  It encrypts and decrypts, but some of the characters in the .PNG are replaced with these characters: 
ï¿½

I figure it is a Unicode error, but I dunno what's up.  Here's the code:

```
        byte[] encrypted_data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file_data);
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = key;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray =
        cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(encrypted_data, 0, encrypted_data.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
```

Comment: Why are you processing binary data with a text method?

Comment: Why are you reading PNG data as UTF-8? It's binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a unicode error. You have involved the encoding where it doesn't belong by reading the data as a string, so the error is before the code that you have shown.

You should read the data as binary data so that you get it as a byte array from the start, so that you can skip the conversion into unicode and back as that is what causes the error.